# Leaflet: How to move the layer-control menu?

Tags: layers, leaflet

This might be a silly question, but I could not find a documented way to achieve this.

I'd like to freely position the layer-control menu, probably to the top left near the default zoom-in/out button.

My layer control looks like this:

```
// Group layers as overlay pane
overlayPane = {
  "Endpoints" : endpointMarkerLayer,
  "Links" : linkLineLayer
};

// Add a layer control element to the map
layerControl = L.control.layers(null, overlayPane);
layerControl.addTo(map);
```

Where `endpointMarkerLayer` and `linkLineLayer` are layers containing markers and polylines respectively.

Is there an option to specify where the menu should appear?
Or alternatively, how can I get a reference to the DOM-objcet of the control-menu, such that I could assign it a custom class and override positioning in CSS?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

According to the docs [here](http://leafletjs.com/reference.html#control-layers-options), you can pass the position in as an option when creating the layer control.

Available positions are outlined [here](http://leafletjs.com/reference.html#control-positions)

```
overlayPane = {
  "Endpoints" : endpointMarkerLayer,
  "Links" : linkLineLayer,
};

// Add a layer control element to the map
layerControl = L.control.layers(null, overlayPane, {position: 'topleft'});
layerControl.addTo(map);
```

Comment: Wow, how did I miss that. Feeling stupid.^^

Comment: Feeking the same way here...

Answer (score 6):

Kelso's answer is correct. However, the documentation (and API) is a bit confusing. For example, to create a custom info box, based on this example: http://leafletjs.com/examples/choropleth.html you can do this:

```
var mapInfo = L.control({position:'topleft'});

info.onAdd = function (map) {
  this._div = L.DomUtil.create('div', 'info'); // create a div with a class "info"
  this.update();
  return this._div;
};

// method that we will use to update the control based on feature properties passed
info.update = function (props) {
    this._div.innerHTML = '<h4>US Population Density</h4>' +  (props ?
    '<b>' + props.name + '</b><br />' + props.density + ' people / mi<sup>2</sup>'
    : 'Hover over a state');
};

info.addTo(map);
```

The options are set on the control object. So one may *think* you can do this to position an overlay control:

```
// incorrect
var layerControl = L.control({position:'topleft'}).layers(null, mapOverlays).addTo(map);
```

The correct way to do this, as stated above, is:

```
// correct
var layerControl = L.control.layers(null, mapOverlays, {position:'topleft'}).addTo(map);
```