# qgis2web leaflet: change position of layers control box

Tags: leaflet, javascript, html, qgis2web, css

I exported a leaflet-webmap with qgis2web. On the top-left, there are the controls (like zooming, serching etc.). On the top-right, there is the layers control box (checking/unchecking the layers of the map). This is the one I want to change.

I want to move the layers control box to the left side, under the other control-box. When checking the source-code in my browser, the index.html shows a line `<div class="leaflet-top leaflet-right">` - however, if I look to my saved index.html, there is no such line - it seems to be generated from somewhere else. But from where? I checked the files in css and js folders - found nothing. How can I change the position of this box?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your question has already been asked [here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/41768/leaflet-how-to-move-the-layer-control-menu?rq=1) before.

Nevertheless:

There is a 'position' option in several elements in Leaflet like `L.control` to specify where in the map the element should appear.

Look in your index.html where the `L.control.layers` is defined and add `{position: 'topleft'}`

For example:

```
L.control.layers(layers, basemaps, {position: 'topleft'}).addTo(map);
```